# Bayer image - greenish

Tags: image, image-processing

we are integrating a new imaging sensor (OV2718 over MIPI) to an embedded system (RV1126+Linux). V4L2 works ok, but it looks like the Bayer raw image collected from the sensor is wrong, i.e., the picture is too greenish.

We captured a Bayer raw image of a white paper, but both the raw image and coverted RGB image looks wrong:

1. RGB:[white paper, converted from the Bayer raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YcZF.png)
2. Bayer raw: We further looked into the binary raw image and we figured out that the G channels (sensor is BGGR) is almost doubled compared to the other two channels (R and B).
   [cropped, 12bits value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhgWe.png)

We also had another sensor connected to the same dev board via the same interface (OS04a10 over mipi). both the binary Bayer raw and converted RGB image looks fine.

The question is - is the Bayer raw from the new sensor (OV2718) correct? If the raw is wrong, can someone shed some lights here on how to debug this issue?

---

edit1:
a)**updated** Bayer Raw from ov2718 (1920x1080,10bit, BGGR, white paper):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k9ghuTkTozI8D3yNaRlqpqTWWCzr06qS/view?usp=sharing

b)**updated** Bayer raw from os04a10(2688x1520,10bit, BGGR)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ugu-e8GCieqL_ZNjoIhZ_zjw4Hc64lS3/view?usp=sharing

---

Comment: To confirm whether the data was in the expected format and so on, could you post the raw data with no decoding done to it?

Comment: debayering must always be followed by white balance, and dark field correction too (unless you do that on the bayer image itself). you can't just trust the raw values to be scaled/biased "pleasingly".

Comment: harold - edited the original post to include the raw image captured from both OV2718 and the original sensor (OS04a10).

Comment: Chris - thanks for the input. I was told the same by someone. but my argument is that how white balance can be done without debayering? Most of the white balancing alg depends on demosaiced image, isn't it?

Comment: not talking about the white balance but the dark field correction, which _can_ be applied to un-debayered raw data. it's supposed to compensate for sensor noise too, not just stray illumination. -- since we're talking about darkfield correction, there's "brightfield" correction too, which removes vignettes by scaling the entire image. if the brightfield is "white" for whatever you consider white, that in itself would represent a white balance correction. it's got one factor *per sensor pixel*, instead of treating all pixels of one color with the same factor.

Comment: I played with the data a little. I'm getting a terribly overexposed picture of someone in a presumably grayish sweatshirt against a bright yellow lit room. could also be a "white" room with the clothing being bluish. -- I can't see any green hue.

Comment: this is just the planes reassembled, ignoring pixel shifts (didn't debayer "properly"): https://i.stack.imgur.com/06g7t.jpg

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, this is 10bits raw data, hence you may want to convert into uint8 by dividing each pixels by 4.

Comment: yes, you said that before, and I handled the data correctly. it *is* overexposed and clipped. please take a picture that isn't overexposed.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, you are correct, I sent a wrong raw file. please find the corrected raw files below: edit1: a)updated Bayer Raw from ov2718 (1920x1080,10bit, BGGR, white paper): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k9ghuTkTozI8D3yNaRlqpqTWWCzr06qS/view?usp=sharing

b)updated Bayer raw from os04a10(2688x1520,10bit, BGGR) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ugu-e8GCieqL_ZNjoIhZ_zjw4Hc64lS3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: for your own testing/development, I'd recommend that you make the camera look at something remotely color-chart-ish so you can tell whether primary colors are mapped and adjusted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is - is the Bayer raw from the new sensor (OV2718) correct? If the raw is wrong, can someone shed some lights here on how to debug this issue?

Yes, the raw data is "correct".

It may be unusual for the different color filters to differ so much in their relative intensities, i.e. how much they attenuate even the light they are intended to let pass.

It shouldn't matter to the processing that must follow anyway:

- [dark field subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-frame_subtraction) (accounts for additive noise)
- [flat field division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-field_correction) (accounts for individual pixel sensitivities and vignetting)
- white balance/scaling (accounts for color of scene lighting)

Rabbit hole: [https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/ICCV19_Tutorial_MSBrown.pdf](https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/%7Embrown/ICCV19_Tutorial_MSBrown.pdf)

---

There is one possibility you might wanna explore: can the sensor adjust the *gain* of one Bayer "subgrid" (the B/G1/G2/R subgrids) independently from the others? It shouldn't have that ability because that's a lot of extra logic for no real benefit. If it does however, maybe that is set to different values, which might explain the seriously differing averages.

Comment: Very nice slides you link here! Thank you!